# How to set path for "cassandra-topology.properties"?

Tags: cassandra

I'm looking for a way to set path for "cassandra-topology.properties" so that Cassandra can get this file from the given path. Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks,
Bhathiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** Cassandra expects the topology files to be in a specific directory (based on what C* you installed):

- OSS C* packaged installs: /etc/cassandra/conf
- OSS C* binary installs: /conf
- DSE packaged installs: /etc/dse/cassandra
- DSE binary installs: /resources/cassandra/conf